# Amazon AWS: Stop service after free limits

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying out AWS features, and I intend to only try the "free trails" first.

Is there a safety that I dont endup being charged for crossing the free limit.
Like a button switch like "Stop after free trail"?

this is for my entire aws account, not limited to any one service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no automatic "stop after free trial" feature.

Your AWS Account is a full account, with all capabilities active. The AWS billing system, however, will not charge for services consumed within the [free usage tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/).

You will [receive emails](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/12/aws-free-tier-usage-alerts-automatically-notify-you-when-you-are-forecasted-to-exceed-your-aws-service-usage-limits/) when it is forecasted that you will exceed the free tier and you can [Monitor Your AWS Free Tier Usage](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-monitor-your-aws-free-tier-usage/) in the AWS management console.